# Drop down population

Tags: php, ajax

How can I get value from database using AJAX? I am creating salary slip in this when I select department auto populate employee name then select employee name auto populate Bank A/c No. and Basic salary. I tried using this code but getting problem in last drop down.

```
function dep(str) {
    var a;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        a = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    a.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (a.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("empid").innerHTML = a.responseText;
        }

    }
    a.open("GET", "emp.php?j=" + str, true);
    a.send();
}

function employee(str) {
    //alert("hello");
    var b;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        b = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    b.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (b.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("kam").innerHTML = b.responseText;
        }

    }
    b.open("GET", "ac.php?k=" + str, true);
    b.send();
}

function ac(str) {
    var d;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        d = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    d.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (d.readyState == 4) {
            document.getElementById("ja").innerHTML = d.responseText;
        }
    }
    d.open("GET", "insert.php?m=" + str, true);
    d.send();
}
```

PHP Coding

```
<?php
    //error_reporting(0);
    include("db.php");
    if(isset($_REQUEST['j']))
    {
        $g=$_REQUEST['j'];
        $sel=mysql_query("select * from employees where depid='$g'");
        while($l=mysql_fetch_array($sel))
        {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $l[0];?>"><?php echo $l[1]. " ". $l[2];?></option>
        <?php
        } 
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['k']))
    {
        $o=$_REQUEST['k'];
        echo $sel1=mysql_query("select ac from salary where empid='$o'");
        while($i=mysql_fetch_array($sel1))
        {
        ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $i[0];?>"><?php echo $i[0];?></option>
        <?php 
        }
    }


    if(isset($_REQUEST['m']))
        {
        $ko=$_REQUEST['m'];
        echo $sel5=mysql_query("select basicsalary from salary where ac='$ko'");
        while($i1=mysql_fetch_array($sel5))
        {
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $i1[0];?>"><?php echo $i1[0];?></option>
        <?php 
        }
    }
    ?>
```

my database file :

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("payslip") or die(mysql_error()); 
?>
```

Comment: @Darius: how do you know jQuery's the solution to the issue?

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy because it's easy to use $.post to access the script that pulls out data from DB - that's how I do it

Comment: no i am not using jQuery.

Comment: @Daedalus I'm not saying it is - that's why I asked not posted an answer

Comment: @ebizz What are the contents of the `obj` parameter?  An example would help here.

Comment: there is bank account no.

Comment: @ebizz Like I said, _an example would help here_.  Examples don't have to contain the actual data.. you could fill it with zeros for all I care..  but we need something.

Comment: @ebizz When you say *last drop down* what do you mean, `ac` method? Do you think you should show as the `html` code even the `php` file the `ajax` requests. Try also to implement the other states too and the `status`.

Comment: in last step i am not getting account no. drop down

Comment: @ebizz Without seeing your php, or an example of your data, this question is impossible to answer.  If you will not provide it, I'm going to vote to close.  There is nothing wrong with the above js.

Comment: @ebizz Since you use `GET` method type in your broswer `insert.php?m=` with a valid value for `m` to see if you have any result. If not there is something wrong with you `php` code.

Comment: @ebizz I have one more advice use `json` in order to populate your drop down.

Comment: Will you give me code for that.

Comment: We also need the `db.php` file.

Comment: <?php
 mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_select_db("payslip") or die(mysql_error());
?>

Comment: Post it properly, in you question.

Comment: @ebizz Provide the db schema and try my code. Tell if you get any errors.

Comment: where i find db schema.

Comment: Go to your database `use paylip;` -> `describe salary;` or describe what columns do you have in your table. **Did you tried the code I post it?**

Comment: ya but didn't find anything

Comment: @ebizz What you didn't find? I change my script a bit, test it again, type `insert.php?m=` in your broswer with a valid value for `m`, you should see an error otherwise a text with the options.

Answer (score 0):

**This not a solution, just an attempt to debug your code.**

Please read  [PHP](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_select_php.htm).

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("payslip") or die(mysql_error());

if (isset($_GET['m'])) {
    $ko = $_GET['m'];
    $sel5 = mysql_query("select basicsalary from salary where ac='$ko'", $conn);

    if (!$sel5) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }

    $options = "";
    while ($i1 = mysql_fetch_array($sel5, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $options .= "<option value={$i1[0]}>{$i1[0]}</option>\r\n";
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
    echo $options;
} else {
    echo "empty data request";
}
```